# unable to get child element to fadein when hovering over parent element

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein, jquery-hover

I am new to JQuery and am currently attempting to get a child element to fade in to display product information when the user hovers over the parent element.

This is as far as I've got with out luck:

jQuery:

```
$('.overlay-wrap').hover(function(){

    $('.product-overlay', this).fadeIn(2000, "swing");

    },

    $('.product-overlay', this).fadeOut("fast");

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay-wrap">
            <div class="product-overlay"><a href="#">Name of the product</a></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay-wrap{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
    .product-overlay{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        left:0px;
        background:#000;
        opacity:0.5;
        padding:5px;
        width:100%;
        display:none;
    }
    .product-overlay a{
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:20px;
    }
```

Heres a simplified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp6DS/) of what I have so far.

Why isn't the child element fading in when I hover over the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create a proper function handler to the hover stop event.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/pp6DS/6/)

```
$('.overlay-wrap').hover(
    function () { $('.product-overlay', this).fadeIn(2000, "swing"); },
    function () { $('.product-overlay', this).fadeOut("fast");       }
                        );
```